# Toom-Cook multiplication algorithm implementation

Tags: c, algorithm, biginteger, largenumber

I have a task to implement Toom-Cook 3-way multiplication algorithm. I'm following description on wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toom%E2%80%93Cook_multiplication , and I managed to store two big numbers into strings and split the strings into smaller ones according to the "Splitting" step on the wikipedia page. The next step is "evaluation", and I have to calculate a new number p0 = m0 + m2 ("Faster evaluation" by Bordrato - found on the same page) where m0 and m2 are the digits which I created by splitting the large number (in the previous step). The problem is that I cannot simply add up m0 and m2, since those two numbers can still be very large and impossible to add together in a standard way. Does this mean that I have to implement my own algorithm for adding large numbers (as well as substracting and dividing, since they are also needed), or am I missing something? If anyone could link me a possible implementation or even a pseudo code, it would be appreciated.

Comment: Adding up two big integers is very very simple. Add and carry, add and carry, add and carry... Subtraction is similarly easy. Division is slightly tougher, but it's basically just long division on arrays.

Comment: I assume when you say you stored the numbers in strings that you mean arrays of base 2^k digits for some suitably large k (like 32).  It would be silly to use character strings. For the bignum ops, why not use an established C library like `gmp` or maybe `mini-gmp`?

Comment: @Gene what do you mean by “arrays of base 2^k digits”? Can you give an example?

Comment: Look at how bigints are implemented by `mini-gmp`. The digits are unsigned longs, so k=32 on most architectures.  Even the Wiki article says to pick a suitable power of 2 for the modulus. It uses powers of 10 in the example only for easy reading by humans.

Comment: @Gene is the 2^32 will be the max value of each limbs before it goes back to 0?

Comment: @kabibesadagat No. A 32-bit unsigned int can represent 2^32 values, but one of those is zero. So the largest is 2^32 - 1.   Ex: 9 is the biggest digit when the limb is 10.

Comment: @Gene I see, I have a question though, you said, "```Look at how bigints are implemented by mini-gmp. The digits are unsigned longs, so k=32 on most architectures.```"... I don't know about **mini gmp**, but aren't ```unsigned long```s are 64 bit? so having a base of 2^32 meaning they are only using half of the bits of ```unsigned long``` as their base for each digit and not base 2^64?

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement your own methods for addition, subtraction, modulo, etc. Sometime ago I was trying to implement a BigInteger library and I have found some resources that may be useful for you.

- BigNum Math book (as pointed by the previous answer)
- Java OpenJdk
  [BigInteger implementation](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/00cd9dc3c2b5/src/share/classes/java/math/BigInteger.java), with documentation
- Algorithms and data structures The basic toolbox, (I have learned Karatsube of this book).

By the way, I recommend to use base 2 for your numbers([see here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7212554/what-base-would-be-more-appropriate-for-my-biginteger-library)) because you can take advantage of the nature of the computer to make your operations more easy and fast.

Answer (score 0):

[LibTomMath](http://www.libtom.net/LibTomMath/) is open source and includes a Toom-Cook multiplication; have a look.